# how to check if there is not supported parameter given in get method in express/node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I have a method in my node.js backend:

```
app.get('/reports', function(req, res){

  var amount = req.param('amount');
  var longitude = req.param('long');
  var latitude = req.param('lat');
  var distance = req.param('distance');
  var numberOf = req.param('numberOf');
```

and I'm using a validator.js ( https://github.com/chriso/validator.js ) plugin to validate it on the input.

so for example for the amount it looks like this:

```
var amount = req.param('amount');


    if (amount && !validator.isNumeric(amount)) {
        return res.status(406).send("Please send a valid amount");
    }
```

and it works pretty well, when user types: `/reports?amount=aaa` he will get the error. When he types `/reports?amount=2` he will get filtered results.

But for example, when the user types some random parameter, e.g. `/reports$randomString=21` I want to return him a message, that sorry, but `randomString` is not a valid parameter. How can I do it without knowing what kind of different strings users can type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express will set [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) object that contains all query params provided by the request.

You can iterate over this object to verify all parameters are indeed valid.

for example:

```
req.query.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
  // your validations here
  if (key != 'amount' && key != 'long' && .... ) {
     // wrong param, throw error
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, I'm new to java script, but if you mean `for (var i = 0; i < req.query.length; i++) {` then how can I check if any of the parameters inside is different than the 5 of which I accept?

Comment: one more thing - why did you exactly type `keys(o)` here? what is this `(o)`?